# How to use boto3 to determine region/availability zone of a primary cluster given an RDS database

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-rds

Given that I have a database name passed in as parameter, how can I get the availability zone/region of the primary database cluster using boto3? I tried using `describe_db_clusters()` and `describe_db_instances()` but could not get the information that I was looking for there (availability zone/region of primary cluster)